# Can I have a ApplicationSettings on a separate file, if so, how?

Tags: .net, web-applications

After reading about the differences between *appSettings* and *applicationSettings* in a web.config file, I'd rather use the *applicationSettings* section and benefit from the strongly typed settings. But with the *appSettings* section, you could previously have a separate  section on a different file and simply reference it on the web.config using the 'file=' attribute on the  section [as so](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18880).

I would like to keep my application settings separate from the web.config file so that when the user changes any of the settings, the application is not restarted automatically.

Is there a similar way to achieve this using the new ***applicationSettings*** section and benefit from strongly typed settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via visual studio.  The steps are outlined here.
[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: It is all the way at the bottom -- use alternate settings shows you how to make a new settings file.

Comment: I found a more recent version of this article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx ... It does indeed indicate you only have to create another .settings file, although my problem is addressed more deeply on this msdn forum post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e7848e05-a265-4392-a7f5-35165fec34e5

Answer (score 0):

Use the application's executable name and add .comfig on the end. Then store the file in the same directory.

```
e.g. myappname.exe.config
```

There is an excellent article on TechRepublic that details how to do this.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1044975.html

Comment: Its a web app, there's no exe here. The article you mention talks about the old appSettings, not the new applicationSettings section I'm inquiring about.

Comment: Ok no problem. I will leave the answer here in case anyone with an EXE hits this question via a web search.